# How do I block and wait for an Apex job to finish executing?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I need to run an apex job inside a test:

```
test.startTest();

Id jobid = Database.executeBatch(new ApexJob());
```

and then wait for the apex job to finish and then stop the test:

```
test.stopTest();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's *exactly* what `Test.stopTest()` does. It makes sure all asynchronous processing has finished before continuing on with the rest of the logic in your `testMethod`.

```
static testMethod void testSomeAsyncProcess()
{
    Test.startTest();
        someAsyncProcess();
    Test.stopTest();
    // all asynchronous processing is now complete.
    // make your assertions here
}
```

From the [Test.stopTest()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_stopTest) docs:

> **Usage**
>
> Each test method is allowed to call this method only once. Any code that executes after the stopTest method is assigned the original limits that were in effect before startTest was called. **All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes are run synchronously.**